# Android ScrollView not vertically filling layout on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

This is quite strange. I have a set of tabs, and on one (well really two but they are the same thing with slightly different content) is acting up. I have two XML files. One is for landscape and it works just fine. The other is for portrait and it is misbehaving. Beneath I will attach the xml. The way the page is setup, it has a linear layout as the root layout. Then there is a scroll view containing a horizontal linear layout and a relative layout. They are supposed to stack on each other. To that end, I did the opposite of the landscape version. I set the height to 0dp and the weight to 1 on each of the layouts. On the landscape version, this works fine and spaces them out like they are supposed to. The scroll view has fill view window marked as true and the tag or declaration or whatever it is is after the height.

But on the portrait version, it renders in Eclipse properly but does not render on my device properly (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1). I am specifically targeting this screen and device, if that's relevant.

Does anyone have any idea?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- the id itemListItemList is named that way on purpose -->
    <!-- This will be filled programmatically as items are added to the inventory -->

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/itemListScrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/itemListItemList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemListRelLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/itemListItemName"
                style="@style/item_list_label_style"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/label_background"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:hint="@string/item_list_item_label"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:paddingLeft="11dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/itemListItemTag"
                style="@style/item_list_label_style"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/label_background"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:hint="@string/item_list_tag_label"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:paddingLeft="11dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/itemListItemDescSym"
            style="@style/item_list_label_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:background="@drawable/label_background"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="@string/item_list_desc_sym_label"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:paddingLeft="11dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/itemListItemExceptions"
            style="@style/item_list_label_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/itemListItemDescSym"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:background="@drawable/label_background"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="@string/item_list_exceptions_label"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:paddingLeft="11dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <!--
             <Button
            android:id="@+id/item_list_void_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_list_clear_button"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_list_clear_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
            android:text="@string/item_list_void_button" />
        -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/item_list_edit_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/item_list_edit_button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/item_list_clear_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/item_list_clear_button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/item_list_void_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/item_list_void_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "not render on my device properly" schematic would be helpful

Comment: What happens is that the scrollview has 0 height. This causes the relative layout and it's controls to be at the top of the screen rather than the bottom. I suppose I could use a relative layout instead of a vertical and force it but I'm not even sure if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

set android:fillViewport="true" at scrollview tag